# MS Flow 'The requested resource doesn't exist' with Excel file

Tags: excel, flow

This is happening constantly the last few days.
The flow pulls the attachment from an email when arrives to a folder. The attachments is a `.xlsx`.
Then the flow creates a table in the same sheet, then it iterates each row that is not empty and it passes that values to a Apply to each block.

This is where it fails, I have to edit the Flow every time it fails, and just select again the same file, I mean, nothing else changes. [image]

This is the error

[image]

And this is the flow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it is throwing error because it is unable to read the specified "table" in the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a delay. The [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/) says that an Excel file may be locked for an update or delete up to 6 minutes since the last use of the connector. So what I did is to add a Delay of 10 minutes to be sure that the file is available when the `List rows present in a table` does its thing.

Answer (score 1):

I frequently run into this issue, and have found it to stem from one of two root causes.

#1: If you're posting to the document library a new "status.xlsx" file each time, then when you "select again the same file" you're actually selecting a different file--even if you're reusing the same filename. In the flow action, instead of selecting a file use dynamic content to enter the fileID and table name as custom values.

#2: Often, it seems that a flow believes an action within a file on OneDrive or SharePoint is complete before it's actually complete. I've worked around this lag by embedding delays (e.g., 30 seconds) in a flow between actions like creating a table and getting the rows from that table.

Update: Re #2, here's another technique I just tried and seemed to work upon initial testing--loop until file/table access is confirmed.
[image: Power Automate flow actions: initialize variable as false; within do until loop, attempt to perform desired action followed by action to set variable to true only upon success of desired action]

Comment: Yes, I actually forgot about this question. I found something usefull this the [Excel MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/): "An Excel file may be locked for an update or delete up to 6 minutes since the last use of the connector." So I added a 10mins delay just to be sure. Thank you, David.